# How can i select class="logo" element in shadow-root using protractor+typescript

Tags: typescript, xpath, automation, protractor, ui-automation

How can i select class='logo' in shadow-root

[pic of html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya52v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try

```
const logo = element(by.deepCss('.logo'));
```

You can also refer following links for more information

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.deepCss

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver

Happy coding~

==================================================
Solution in Selenium + Java

```
public class SeleniumJava {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void shaddowTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/krishnamajgaonkar/Desktop/Work/QAAuto/chromedriver-mac-64bit");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://accounts.careerbuilder.com/share/login.aspx?next=http%3a%2f%2femployer.careerbuilder.com%2fjobposter%2fmycb.aspx");
        driver.findElement(By.name("cbsys_login_email")).sendKeys("testusercb@mailinator.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("cbsys_login_password")).sendKeys("Stackoverflow12");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnsigninemp")).click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("HandleException");
        }
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        WebElement logo = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('cbd-intl-header').querySelector('cut-wc-header').shadowRoot.querySelector('.logo')");
        System.out.println(logo.getAttribute("class"));
    }
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

output:

`logo`

Comment: not working, getting error : NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, * /deep/ .logo)

Comment: Is it possible to share the URL on which you are facing this issue?

Comment: yaa sure, please login on https://accounts.careerbuilder.com/share/login.aspx?next=http%3a%2f%2femployer.careerbuilder.com%2fjobposter%2fmycb.aspx with id: testusercb@mailinator.com and pass: Stackoverflow12 after that open https://homepage.cba.careerbuilder.com/homepage/recent-activity now you able to see 'logo' on top right corner

Comment: @RohitGupta I have updated the answer with Selenium+Java solution. If you can see, I am able to access the logo class inside `shadow-root`, and to prove it, I have printed the class name. I know this solution is not for protractor but you can refer the solution and try to implement in typescript. thanks~